# restore files in path /var/lib/dpkg lock

Tags: lock

I accidentally deleted /var/lib/dpkg/lock and /var/lib/dpkg /frontend files from my ubuntu 22.04 system.
How do I return them?

Answer (score 1):

Those look like:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 nov  3 06:04 lock
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 apr  3  2022 lock-frontend
```

Recreate by

```
sudo -i
cd /var/lib/dpkg/
touch lock lock-frontend
chown root:root lock lock-frontend
chmod 640 lock lock-frontend
```